# Android RelativeLayout and OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I found many many threads and answers on how to make a Relative layout respond to click event. I've implemented my layout according to them. But still OnClickListener is not called. I have also given selector for it and it works well.

my_list_item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/air.com.jingit.mobile"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/my_list_selector">

<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarHeight"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<com.uma.mobile.view.CustomTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    app:typeface="fonts/HelveticaNeue"
    app:customStyle="Regular"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#aaa"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"></FrameLayout>
```

and this is where I inflate the view:

```
public MyListItem(final Context context, final Integer retailerId) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, this);
        image = (SmartImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        userName = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);


        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("INSIDE LIST","CLICK");

            }
        });
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

This Relative layout is added to a linear layout which is inside a scrollview, so that it works like a list view. Does this has something to do???

list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#eee">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listContainer" />
</ScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/up_indicator"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scrollView" />
```

Comment: use`android:clickable="true"` instead of     `android:clickable="false"` to make Layout Clickable

Comment: use view.setOnClickListener

Comment: @Homosapiens Even that didnt work.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have given `android:clickable="true"` for the layout

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have edited the question. Any idea about this?

Comment: @Homosapiens I have edited my question. Can you look to it.

Answer (score 2):

Once i had a `RelativeLayout` not firing `onClick` event and it was because i had a `Button` in the middle of it, and the `Button`'s onClick event was being fired, instead of the `RelativeLayout` one. Solved it implementing a listener for both of them:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Handle onClick 
    }
};
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(listener);
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnClickListener` in your `RelativeLayout java Class`